# How Can I perform Integration Testing against Oracle UCM with consistent data?

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, oracle-ucm

I have a web Application that uses the **CIS-API** to communicate with **Oracle UCM**. 
I've been tasked with writing automated tests on the web Interface. 
I've been able to get that running with [selenium-webdriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver). 
However,  due to the nature of the site and my tests, the tests are somewhat tightly coupled to the Data.

How can I do proper Automated Testing on my site and ensure consistent data for my tests?

**Oracle UCM** is backed by an **MS SQL Server** Database.

Comment: In what way are the tests tightly coupled to data?

Comment: @PatMeeker UCM is managing Documents * Metadata.  My tests currently expect Documents in a certain order with certain properties, and then they get shuffled between different workflows.

Comment: How about making each test first create the document(s) with whatever metadata/properties needed for the individual test, on the fly, before the testflow. For example, each test would have a setup and teardown, where it creates a document, then tests it, then destroys the document once the test is finished. Then no need to anticipate the documents' order.

Comment: @raystorm i use to work for Stellent then Oracle on UCM team. I might be able to provide some assistence. Shoot me a private email.   Id load all your documents into a map using the api. Then id check your site for those docs by capturing the links on the page. As an initial guess w/o seeing much code

Comment: @PatMeeker, I 'm working Automating my UI to perform a file insert Loop up front for the testing.

Comment: @bcar, I couldn't find in the API how to bulk checkIn documents via a Map.  I found file/fileStream checkins, but from what I could tell it will only do 1 Document at a time.

Comment: I think i misunderstood thd problem you're having. I thought you were looking at the site after upload.

Comment: @PatMeeker If you move turn your Setup+Upload & TearDown+Delete to an actual answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making each test first create the document(s) with whatever metadata/properties needed for the individual test, on the fly, before the testflow. For example, each test would have a setup and teardown, where it creates a document, then tests it, then destroys the document once the test is finished. Then no need to anticipate the documents' order.